# Hide prexcept prompt output

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I am writing a program in Python 2.7 that creates an SSH connection and outputs the results of the command entered. It works fine, but I want to hide the prompt output, or alternatively, is there a way to eliminate the need for prompt?

This is my code responsible for the output:

```
    if cmd == '!':
        print ("Connection terminated.")
        self.session.logout()
        sys.exit(0) 
    else:
        self.session.sendline(cmd)

        with suppress_stdout():
            self.session.prompt()

        return self.session.before
```

A sample output (I want to get rid of the second 'ls'):

```
-> ls
ls
bin    dev   initrd.img      lib32   lost+found  opt   run   sys  var
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  lib64   media       proc  sbin  tmp  vmlinuz
cdrom  home  lib             libx32  mnt         root  srv   usr  vmlinuz.old

->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pexcept prompt() is a special case of the except() that recognizes most types of prompt identifiers. self.session.before was taking everything between the most recently used prompt and the prompt to be used; in other words, it was taking the command entered and the output. To get rid of the repeated command, just eliminate the first word of the string. I did this by splitting the string into a list, and then, printing everything out except for the first element of the list.